# DirectX 9 Terrain genereration C++

Tags: c++, directx, terrain

I am having trouble generating a flat terrain with quads, I think the quads are located correctly but the indices are incorrect.. Can someone please have a look see and tell me what i am doing wrong or how i can fix it? Basically the terrain is displayed but totally wrong. I THINK it is the indices positioning, please help me it would be highly appreciated.

FOR LOOP:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTS; i += 4){
    for(int x = 0; x < j; x ++){
        for(int z = 0; z < j; z ++){
            verts[i] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x, -1.0f, z+1, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            verts[i+1] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1, -1.0f, z+1, n, 1.0f, g, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            verts[i+2] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x, -1.0f, z, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            verts[i+2] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1, -1.0f, z, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            indices[i] = i;
            indices[i+1] = i+1;
            indices[i+2] = i+2;
            indices[i+3] = i+2;
            indices[i+4] = i+1;
            indices[i+5] = i+3;
        }
    }
    //MessageBox(NULL, L"Test", NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: What would be your actual question?

Comment: What is the matter with my code, and how can i arrange the indeces correctly so that it is a quad terrain. NUM_VERTS = 24 and NUM_INDECES = 36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer-most loop does not make sense. Instead, maintain two indices for the vertex buffer and the index buffer like so:

```
int iVertex = 0;
int iIndex = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < j; x ++){
    for(int z = 0; z < j; z ++){
        verts[iVertex  ] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x, -1.0f, z+1, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        verts[iVertex+1] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1, -1.0f, z+1, n, 1.0f, g, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        verts[iVertex+2] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x, -1.0f, z, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        verts[iVertex+3] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1, -1.0f, z, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        indices[iIndex  ] = iVertex;
        indices[iIndex+1] = iVertex+1;
        indices[iIndex+2] = iVertex+2;
        indices[iIndex+3] = iVertex+2;
        indices[iIndex+4] = iVertex+1;
        indices[iIndex+5] = iVertex+3;

        iVertex += 4;
        iIndex += 6;
    }
}
```

I assume that you're aware that the terrain will stretch from `0` to `j + 1` in both `x` and `z` direction.

If it's just a plane, you might also consider using a single quad. If you need multiple triangles, you might consider converting the triangle list to a triangle strip. If you want to stick to the triangle list, you should at least consider removing the duplicate vertices (every vertex in the terrain's center exists four times).

Comment: Yes i am aware that it stretches, that is the problem, i don't know how to create a terrain, can you please help me? and explain why. Thank you for the tip with the loop and thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Oh yeah, j = num_verts/2 to get a squire, but i am assuming that it is wrongly calculated

Comment: If your vertex number is fixed, you should calculate `j = sqrt(num_verts / 4)`. Make sure that this will produce a natural number.

Comment: Ok, i will give it a shot, how can i create a quad terrain? Do you by any chance have a tutorial or a link to an example, i searched for a week now and cannot find anything, i found a directx 11 example but it is to much work to convert my project to directx 11

Comment: *** THANK YOU!!! There is still a bit of errors with the indices tho, The texture seem to be stretched at the bottom right corner of every quad, how can i fix this?

Comment: The texture coordinates of the last vertex are wrong (`iVertex + 3`, coordinates should be `(1, 1)` instead of `(0, 1)`. Just found [this tutorial](http://www.chadvernon.com/blog/resources/directx9/terrain-generation-with-a-heightmap/).

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! YOU ARE MY HERO Haha, i hope i help other people with the same problem with this question, HAVE A GREAT DAY, and sir.... You are a genius :P

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that solved your question to mark the question as solved (click the check mark next to the answer).